# CTE user defined functions group by and row duplications

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, distinct, common-table-expression

i have query with multiple CTEs in it each cte doing  calculations and than i retrieve needed me cows from this cte, its work but  my problem is i came customers who can have multiple contracts and they  are doing  duplications I was trying to illuminate it by using distinct  or group by  but  it didn't  work
here is the query  and its answer

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   ISNULL(g.last_id
                               + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CustomerId ), 1) AS RowId
                       ,c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId
                       ,b.Id
                       ,4 AS EntityState
                       ,c.Id AS contractid
               FROM     dbo.Contract c
                        JOIN dbo.BudgetYear AS b ON YEAR(c.CreateDate) = b.Year
                        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MAX(Id) AS last_id
                                     FROM   [ContractConclusionStatistic]
                                   ) g
               GROUP BY c.[CustomerId]
                       ,last_id
                       ,c.Id
                       ,b.Id
             ),
        cte1
          AS ( SELECT   SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(Id)) OVER ( PARTITION BY [CustomerId] ) AS ProcedureCost
                       ,c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
                       ,c.Id AS contractid
               FROM     dbo.Contract c
               WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId <> 15
               GROUP BY c.[CustomerId]
                       ,Id
             ),
        cte2
          AS ( SELECT   SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(c.Id)) OVER ( PARTITION BY [CustomerId] ) AS SingleVendorCost
                       ,c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
                       ,c.Id AS contractid
               FROM     dbo.Contract c
                        JOIN PurchaseSingleVendor p ON c.PurchaseSingleVendorId = p.Id
               WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId = 15
                        AND c.PurchaseSingleVendorId = 16
                        AND c.PurchaseSingleVendorId = 17
            --and 2 more 
               GROUP BY [c].[CustomerId]
                       ,c.Id
             ),
        cte3
          AS ( SELECT   SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(Id)) OVER ( PARTITION BY [CustomerId] ) AS [CanceledProcedureCost]
                       ,c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
                       ,c.Id AS contractid
               FROM     dbo.Contract c
               WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId = 15
               GROUP BY [c].[CustomerId]
                       ,c.Id
             ),
        cte4
          AS ( SELECT   SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(Id)) OVER ( PARTITION BY [CustomerId] ) AS SingleVendorCost
                       ,c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
                       ,c.Id AS contractid
               FROM     dbo.Contract c
               WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId = 15
               GROUP BY [c].[CustomerId]
                       ,c.Id
             )
     SELECT  DISTINCT
            cte.RowId
        -- ,cte1.CanceledProcedureCost
           ,cte1.ProcedureCost
           ,cte2.SingleVendorCost
           ,cte3.CanceledProcedureCost
           ,cte4.SingleVendorCost
           ,cte.Id AS YearId
           ,cte.CustomerId
           ,cte.contractid
           ,4
     FROM   cte
            LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte.contractid = cte1.contractid
            LEFT  JOIN cte2 ON cte2.CustomerId = cte.CustomerId
                               AND cte.contractid = cte2.contractid
            LEFT JOIN cte3 ON cte3.CustomerId = cte.CustomerId
                              AND cte.contractid = cte3.contractid
            LEFT JOIN cte4 ON cte4.CustomerId = cte.CustomerId
                              AND cte.contractid = cte4.contractid
     GROUP BY cte.CustomerId
           ,cte.RowId
           ,cte1.ProcedureCost
           ,cte2.SingleVendorCost
           ,cte.contractid
           ,cte3.CanceledProcedureCost
           ,cte4.SingleVendorCost
           ,cte.Id

54  NULL    NULL    174000.00   174000.00   4   18000   1100253 4
55  NULL    NULL    174000.00   174000.00   4   18000   1100254 4
56  345191000.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   18000   1100261 4
57  345191000.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   18000   1100262 4
58  345191000.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   18000   1100276 4
59  345191000.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   18000   1100286 4
60  345191000.00    NULL    NULL    NULL    4   18000   1100297 4
61  NULL    NULL    180000.00   180000.00   4   21065   1100188 4
62  NULL    NULL    NULL            NULL    4   21065   1100232 4
63  NULL    NULL    180000.00   180000.00   4   21065   1100255 4
64  NULL    NULL    180000.00   180000.00   4   21065   1100256 4
65  NULL    NULL    180000.00   180000.00   4   21065   1100257 4
```

any ideas how to get rid off duplications ?
here I am selecting  `cte.Contractid` just to show from where duplications came from in original query i am not selection this column but still receiving duplicates

here is what  I am trying to achieve

```
55  345191000.00    NULL    174000.00   174000.00   4   18000   1100254 4
56  NULL            NULL    180000.00   180000.00   4   21065   1100257 4
```

for each Customer ID i need to have one record with data coming from multiple CTEs

Comment: please provide an expected output.

Comment: @Aツ check original question

Comment: what happens with the year?

Comment: @Aツ nothing i am just selecting year id from different table however if year ID for example is going to be 5 insde of 4 as it in example it should create new record for this CustomerID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove all group by except customer, add a group by budgetyear if you want a record per customer and budgetyear, otherwise drop them too.

```
WITH cte AS 
( SELECT ISNULL(g.last_id, 1)
       + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY CustomerId ) AS RowId
       ,c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId
       ,b.Id
       ,YEAR(c.CreateDate) bYear
       ,4 AS EntityState
       ,max(c.Id) AS contractid
  FROM  dbo.Contract c
  JOIN dbo.BudgetYear AS b ON YEAR(c.CreateDate) = b.Year
  CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MAX(Id) AS last_id
               FROM   [ContractConclusionStatistic]
             ) g
  GROUP BY c.[CustomerId], last_id , b.Id,YEAR(c.CreateDate)
), 
cte1 AS 
( SELECT SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(Id)) AS ProcedureCost
       , c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
       , YEAR(c.CreateDate) bYear
  FROM     dbo.Contract c
  WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId <> 15
  GROUP BY c.[CustomerId], YEAR(c.CreateDate)
),
cte2 AS 
( SELECT SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(c.Id)) AS SingleVendorCost
       , c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
       , YEAR(c.CreateDate) bYear  
  FROM dbo.Contract c
  JOIN PurchaseSingleVendor p ON c.PurchaseSingleVendorId = p.Id
  WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId = 15
    AND c.PurchaseSingleVendorId = 16
    AND c.PurchaseSingleVendorId = 17
  GROUP BY [c].[CustomerId], YEAR(c.CreateDate)
),
cte3 AS 
( SELECT SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(Id)) AS [CanceledProcedureCost]
       , c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
       , YEAR(c.CreateDate) bYear
  FROM     dbo.Contract c
  WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId = 15
  GROUP BY [c].[CustomerId], YEAR(c.CreateDate)
),
cte4 AS 
( SELECT SUM(dbo.GetContractCost(Id)) AS SingleVendorCost
       , c.[CustomerId] AS CustomerId -- int
       , YEAR(c.CreateDate) bYear
  FROM     dbo.Contract c
  WHERE    c.PurchaseMethodId = 15
  GROUP BY [c].[CustomerId], YEAR(c.CreateDate)
)
SELECT      cte.RowId
        -- ,cte1.CanceledProcedureCost
           ,cte1.ProcedureCost
           ,cte2.SingleVendorCost
           ,cte3.CanceledProcedureCost
           ,cte4.SingleVendorCost
           ,cte.Id AS YearId
           ,cte.bYear
           ,cte.CustomerId
           ,cte.contractid
           ,4
     FROM   cte
            LEFT JOIN cte1 ON cte.CustomerId= cte1.Customerid
                              and cte.bÝear = cte1.bYear
            LEFT  JOIN cte2 ON cte.CustomerId= cte2.Customerid
                              and cte.bÝear = cte2.bYear
            LEFT JOIN cte3 ON cte.CustomerId= cte3.Customerid
                              and cte.bÝear = cte3.bYear
            LEFT JOIN cte4 ON cte.CustomerId= cte4.Customerid
                              and cte.bÝear = cte4.bYear
```

Comment: thanx a lot! I have only one question way  i need to select  `,max(c.Id) AS contractid` in first CTE?

Comment: your second last column is some countractId, i'm not sure which so i just took the last.